# TensorFlow security: Evaluate untrusted graphDef

Tags: security, tensorflow

Is it safe to have TensorFlow evaluate untrusted graphDefs?

Imagine a web service in which users will send me a graphDef file, which TensorFlow will load and evaluate. What evil can an attacker do by sending this service a malicious graphDef file?

I will limit number of requests per hour, file size, and run time, so DoS shouldn't be too much of an issue. What else could an attacker do, and how can I best prevent / mitigate these attack vectors?

AFAICT Google and the TF docs make no mention of this being an issue, but neither do they say that it is safe.

Comment: At least in the go TF APIs, there are read file and write file operations. I have tested and they can be used be used to read and write arbitrary files.
I could perhaps compile a version of libtensorflow without those kernels.

Comment: The tensorflow team makes no guarantees about evaluating untrusted GraphDefs.

Answer (score 0):

More recent TensorFlow documentation makes it fairly clear that, while one can forbid dangerous operations, the TensorFlow runtime presents a sufficiently large attack surface that one should assume it to be exploitable, and hence, run it in a sandbox or other mitigation.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/v1.9.0/SECURITY.md